Closest Hermitian matrix to arbitrary matrix A
We have a homework like this:
Let $A\in\mathbb{C^{n*n}}$ and show that among all Hermitian matrices $H\in\mathbb{C^{n*n}}$, the matrix $\tfrac{1}{2}(A+A^*)$
is a closest matrix to $A$ in the two-norm.
Hint: Measure closeness in terms of the absolute two-norm error, and exploit the properties of the two-norm. This is a short proof.
My approach is that:
\begin{align*}
\|A-H|_2 &=\|\frac{A-A^*}{2}+\frac{A+A^*}{2}-H\|_2\\
&\geqslant \|\frac{A-A^*}{2}\|_2+\|\frac{A+A^*}{2}-H\|_2\\
&\geqslant \|\frac{A-A^*}{2}\|_2
\end{align*}
Note that $\frac{A+A^*}{2}$ is Hermitian, here we can achieve ''='' if and only if $\|\frac{A+A^*}{2}-H\|_2=0$, i.e. $H=\frac{A+A^*}{2}$.
I checked my proof many times and found nothing wrong, but I didn't use any properties of two norms, and I see people proving this using $\|A^*\|_2=\|A\|_2$, which seems more correct. Is there any mistake in my proof?

How did you leap from the first to the second line above? The triangle inequality usually goes the other way.

Oh YES! You are right, and thank you so much!
